# Get page content by ID (from a plugin)

Tags: plugins, pages, id

I'm stuck on loading page content by id (through a plugin). What I have is the following:

```
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('page_id=39'); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Instead of entering the id "39" though, it needs to come from $user_set_value

I'm able to echo the id like this:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'user_set_value', true);
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

..but how could I go about echoing $user_set_value into the first snippet so it would get the id on the fly?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The values assigned to `$user_set_value` should be stored somehow in some form, usually an option. You will know how the values and where the values are stored. It is easy then from there

```
$user_set_value = get_some_saved_option_value();
$args = array(
    'page_id' => $user_set_value
);

$q = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Just change `get_some_saved_option_value()` with the actual method to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

u tried using:

```
global $post;    
$postid  = $post->ID;
```

the `$post` contains data from the current post or page

EDIT:  for more info see codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/$post.

also i think i may have misunderstood your question, are u after:

```
<?php 
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
//  get user value and assign it here
$user_set_value = get_post_meta($postid, 'user_set_value', true);
wp_reset_query();  ?>
// pass user value into query
<?php $my_query = new WP_Query('page_id='.$user_set_value); ?>
<?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Please be a bit more verbose in your answers. It's impossible to understand your answer in it's current form.